# Which program to use when running javascript code made in notepad

Tags: javascript

Ok, recently I started doing some tutorials in javascript. Soon I had finished doing some coding on notepad, saved it as " .js" but when I tried to open it I could not find a suitable program, hopefully, soomeone can tell me a method of running the code.

The first thing I did was try and download java, but quit the installer after seeing the ad based installer including vosteran, a web browser hijacker which I have had some experience with. Finally, is it necessary to download notepad ++ for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a clear understanding of `JavaScript` and how it interacts with `HTML`.  `Java` and `JavaScript` are two complete differently languages.

`.js` files are usually linked within a `.html` file or some server side language file, i.e. `.php, .aspx`.  And the `HTML` file is opened with your browser, for example, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome or Firefox.

You should include the `.js` file in your `HTML` file using:

```
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Within the `HTML` file you can then invoke the methods and use the variables declared in your custom `.js` file.

Comment: I see, so what your saying is to save the file as .html and then place your script at the beginning of the file, after I have done that will I be able to open this file with a web browser? Please bear in mind I have only been using javascript since this morning and I am quite inexperienced.

Comment: @DavidHamer - correct.  Open the HTML file with the web browser and you will have access to your JavaScript code. Look at a few tutorials, keep practising and you'll get there in the end.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks, but I do really appreciate your help and feedback @DarrenDavies

Comment: @DavidHamer - there's nothing wrong with saying thanks and you're welcome.  If this helped please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh, still does not work, first asks do you want to run/open/save, when I click open comes up with error message - Publisher could not be verified

Answer (score 0):

You run js files in a webbrowser. Include files between   tags.

Example:

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options of running Javascript

1 In the browser

2 Or as a process

Choosing which one depends on your code. Please post an example of a what you are working on.

If your code fits option 1, then you will just need a small HTML file that includes reference to your javascript file.

If your code is not meant for a browser, you will likely need to install Nodejs. This is a CommonJS implementation of server-side js.

A note on Java and Javascript. They are in no way related. Netscape licensed the name from makers of Java and renamed language to Javascript in hopes it would inherate some of Java's popularity.

Comment: Just thinking, I have serious doubts about whether this will actually work as it was from a tutorial from codecademy which seems to be slightly different in it's coding. Here is the code,var myName = "Codecademy";

var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

bounceBubbles();

Comment: This looks like it is meant for a browser. Take a look at Darren Davies answer in including your script in a html.